Can we inscribe a rectangle in the region determined by a function and its translate?
Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in some closed interval $[a, b]$. Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) + c$ for some constant $c$ (without loss of generality assume that $c > 0$). I am interested in if we can always find some $x^* \in (a, b)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that there exists a rectangle of the form $$R_{x^*}:=[x^* - \epsilon, x^*+\epsilon] \times[f(x^*), g(x^*)] = [x^* - \epsilon, x^*+\epsilon] \times[f(x^*), f(x^*)+c],$$ is contained in the region enclosed by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over $[a, b]$.
Continuity alone does not guarantee this happens. To see this set $f(x) = |x|$ and notice that there is no such $x^*$. Note that such functions with this property indeed do exist (take $f(x) = 0$) , but I am not sure how to identify them. Thanks for the help.

Hint: if this is the case, then $x^*$ is simultaneously a local maximum for $f(x)$ and a local minimum for $g(x)$.

@GregMartin: So no such $x^*$ can exist? The points where extrema occur are identical in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ since they are the "same" function.

Please provide a graphical example ($\ne$ counter-example as you do with $|x|$). It might also help you to build hypotheses...

If such a rectangle exists, then $f(x^*) \ge f(x)$ for all $x\in [x^*-\varepsilon,x^*+\varepsilon]$; and also $g(x^*) \le g(x)$ for all $x\in [x^*-\varepsilon,x^*+\varepsilon]$, which means that $f(x^*) \le f(x)$ for all $x\in [x^*-\varepsilon,x^*+\varepsilon]$. Consequently, the only way that such a rectangle can exist is if $f(x)$ is constant on some interval.

Thanks for the answer. Instead of considering those rectangles can I get arbitrarily close to them, for instance can I find $$R_{x^}= [x^ - \epsilon, x^+\epsilon] \times[f(x^) + \delta, f(x^*)+c-\delta],$$ for some $\delta > 0$?

If $f$ is continuous then certainly—rephrase the geometric goal in terms of inequalities of function values (as I did in the answer) and you'll see how to prove it yourself! As a warm-up, convince yourself that it is possible for $f(x)=|x|$, the example you pointed out in the OP.
